# which rails gem for edit-on table(inline edit on table)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to use `gem 'best_in_place'` for edit-on table. but it's not work properly.
Is there other any rails gem for edit-on table?

Comment: Not sure exactly where you're stuck but see if this helps - https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/620

Comment: There is some issue with webpacker

Comment: Are you using it with rails-5 or rails-6?

Comment: No, I am using rails 6

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "It doesn't work" is not actionable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [rails db](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db)? I've used it several times and have been helpful in many cases.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question at all. The OP is asking for an inline javascript solution for editing records not a GUI for the database.